# HQL select ID of entity with max value within group

Tags: c#, sql, hibernate, hql

I have this small entity

```
class Order
{
    public long Id;
    public DateTime Date;
    public long ProductId;
}
```

I want to select `Id` of entity which has `MAX(Date)` among orders grouped by `ProductId`.
Pair (`MAX(Date)`, `ProductId`) is not unique so this query is wrong:

```
select o.Id 
from Order o 
where o.Date = 
   (select max(o2.Date) 
    from Order o2 
    where o2.ProductId = o.ProductId);
```

Do you have any ideas?

Basically what I want is to get most recent Order from group, so if I assume that greater `Id` == newer `Order` this:

```
select o 
from Order o 
where o.Id in 
   (select max(o2.Id) 
    from Order o2 
    group by o2.ProductId);
```

will work for me. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: it is not always the case, what if someone change/update the order date, then your query will not return the correct result.

Comment: 100% correct ;-) therefore I'm asking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

try *self join* instead of *in* query for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

there needs to be optimization in query, but it works for you.

```
List<Order> orders = GetOrders();

        var result = from o in orders
                      group o by new { o.ProductId } into ordGrouping
                      let MaxOrderDate = ordGrouping.Max(od=>od.Date)
                      let OrderID = ordGrouping.First(od=>od.Date.Equals(MaxOrderDate)).Id
                      select new 
                      { 
                          ProductId = ordGrouping.Key.ProductId, 
                          OrderId = OrderID,
                          OrderDate = MaxOrderDate
                      };

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Product ID:{0}, OrderId: {1} Date: {2}", item.ProductId, item.OrderId, item.OrderDate.ToLongDateString() + item.OrderDate.ToLongTimeString()));
        }
```